# Deploy Only Diffs in Webapp with Maven to Remote Server

Tags: tomcat, deployment, maven

I am using cargo:deploy with maven to deploy applications to servers.  This works well, but I recently tried using CloudBees.  They have a similar plugin for their infrastructure. However, it deploys only differences between the old WAR and the new WAR so it is significantly faster. Where cargo:deploy takes me 4 to 6 minutes, the CloudBees method takes less than a minute.

Are there any plugins for Maven that will allow me to deploy only my changes to my own app server? Right now I'm using Tomcat, but would consider switching application servers if there was a good solution for something else.

Comment: Can you run your app server locally, or is the point of this question that it has to be remote?

Comment: The point of the question is to deploy to a remote server--particularly something over the public internet where bandwidth has a significant impact on the deployment time. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: I haven't quite understood yet: Can you not use the CloudBees method for your own server or does that only work for a specific cloud environment?

Comment: It only works for their cloud service (as far as I've been able to tell).  The big thing is I want to be able to deploy a diff of my changes instead of redeploying an entire war to my own server running Tomcat (or I'm open to another app server that gives me this capability).

Comment: Have you checked if you can use JRebel instead which can do such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

You need server side support for receiving the delta, which is where we (cloudbees) get to invoke our secret sauce.

What you would need is a deployment service on the target server that understands whatever delta format gets uploaded.

It is not to tricky to do in some ways... The war has built in checksums, so if an entry in the war has the same path, last-modified, Crc and size then it is a good candidate for exclusion from the delta, so you take a safer hash or two (sha-256 and md5 for example, to give to different functions to compare with) and if those hashes are the same! Exclude from the delta.

A fancy tomcat-deployer web app could support such deployment, but you'd want to lock it down for production, but anyway why host yourself when you can GSETDIFY

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in Tomcat, you can use the [Tomcat Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/) for Maven

It's not difficult to configure, just check the Tomcat manager application url because it is changed from Tomcat 6 (http://tomcat_server:8080/manager/) to Tomcat 7 (http://tomcat_server:8080/manager/html).

The plugin runs after the "package" build phase, so it does direct deploy of the generated war to a remote server where Tomcat is running.

Comment: Doesn't that redeploy the entire war--not just a delta of the differences?

Answer (score 0):

I find I get out of memory errors in the server, after a few cargo deployments.
You could use the maven wagon ssh extension.  It could upload based on the expanded war.
Here is the usage doc:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html

But not sure how to get it to only upload changed files.  With ant there was a file cache component which would cache the checksum of the files, and only reupload if the checksum had changed.

Even once you have uploaded the files, a restart might be required as tomcat is not very good with hot deployments.